# Quotes in commands - grep example

Tags: grep

I wanted to know when to use quotes with grep or other tools. For instance the following two command give the same results.

```
[Jhm@localhost /]$ grep Hello ./testfile 
 Hello world

[Jhm@localhost /]$ grep "Hello" ./testfile 
 Hello world
```

Does it mater if a word is in quotes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only if the word contains characters that have special meaning to the shell.

```
grep "Hello?" ./testfile
```

will search for the literal string `Hello?` in the file. However, for example,

```
grep Hello? ./testfile
```

will search for the string `HelloA` if there is a file `HelloA` in your current directory, because `?` will match any single character as a glob pattern.

I'm assuming you are not surprised that

```
grep Hello World ./testfile
```

and

```
grep "Hello World" ./testfile
```

are different.